# Haskell Happstack, can I use a string with html tags as response?

Tags: haskell, happstack

```
    module Main where

    import Happstack.Lite
    import Text.Html

    main :: IO ()
    main = serve Nothing $ msum [
              nullDir >> ok homePage
            , notFound page404  
        ]

    homePage :: Response
    homePage = toResponse $ do
        p (toHtml "hello") +++ 
            strong (toHtml "BOLD")

    page404 :: Response
    page404 = toResponse "<strong>How do I parse the tag STRONG?</strong>"
```

Hi, I'm new to happstack. I'm wondering if there's a way I can just display a string with html tags as response instead of using a html template library?

In the above code, the `<strong>` tag in page404 is escaped, so I got "`<strong>How do I pase the tag BOLD?</strong>`" as response, while the one homePage is rendered as "**How do I parse the tag BOLD**".

Do I have to parse the string first? But wouldn't that be too slow if the html string is large?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the HTML is escaped? Looking at the [ToMessage String instance](http://happstack.com/docs/happstack-server-7.0.2/doc/html/happstack-server/src/Happstack-Server-Response.html#ToMessage), it looks like the response type is the only thing that's wrong. In that case you have a number of options: You can newtype String and create a separate instance, but with a different content type, or you can use different combinators.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I successfully compiled and ran the above code. I don't think there's a type error. The tag is escaped, for example, in route `http://localhost:8000/no-such-route`

Comment: I didn't claim that there is. Only that you'll need to alter the response type, because the `ToMessage String` instance sets it to text/plain rather than text/html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`ToMessage String`](http://happstack.com/docs/happstack-server-7.0.2/doc/html/happstack-server/src/Happstack-Server-Response.html#line-111) instance sets the response type to text/plain rather than text/html.

You can either write your own instance for a newtyped `String` that is essentially a copy of the original instance, but with the response type set to text/html, or use different facilities in the library to alter the response type.

Also, you should probably note that sending a 200 HTTP response on a 404 error is confusing.